# Erlang ETS with bag type elements ordering

Tags: sorting, erlang, ets

I have some code like this:

```
Table = ets:new(table, [bag]),
true = ets:insert(Table, {bucket_1, some_value_1}),
true = ets:insert(Table, {bucket_1, some_value_2}),
true = ets:insert(Table, {bucket_1, some_value_3}),

LookupResult = ets:lookup(Table, bucket_1),
?_assertEqual(
    [{bucket_1, some_value_1}, {bucket_1, some_value_2}, {bucket_1, some_value_3}],
    LookupResult
).
```

Is ETS guarantees ordering of elements within bucket? Should I expect, that ETS saves order of elements, as elements has been added to table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [specification of `lookup/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#lookup-2) says:

> [...] the time order of object insertions is preserved; the first
>   object inserted with the given key will be first in the resulting
>   list, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I've found this words just 5 seconds ago. Thanks =)